# Авторизация ASP.NET через внешние сервисы

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, google-oauth2, owin

Создал чистый ASP.NET MVC Identity User проект.

Установил SSL под постоянный порт: `https://localhost:44392/`

Создал проект в Google APIs, получил id & secret key.

Расскоментировал в файле: `Startup.Auth.cs` код и заполнил данными:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
     ClientId = "тутИдентфикатор.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     ClientSecret = "тутСекретныйКод",
     Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
});
```

получилось после рендеринга в модуле авторизации ожидаемый результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше я пытаюсь авторизироваться через учетную запись Google
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тут казус, я пробовал и другую учетную запись, но в итоге переход на представление с установкой пароля не работает. Я по прежнему остаюсь на странице авторизации после всего этого. Не у меня одного такие проблемы, но и там народ не понял что делать. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: делал по офф гайду и безуспешно...
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: Покажите какие запросы делает ваш браузер, начните с последних.